# When to use clone()

Tags: jquery

I need to dynamically add rows to a table.  I know that I want a model row to look like the following:

```html
<tr id="row">
  <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
  <td><span>TEXT HERE</span></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="asdf"/></td>
</tr>
```

I am wondering if I should just write code to reproduce this row from scratch or if I should use jQuery's clone() method, as so:

```js
//Would document this better in production
$('#row').clone().attr('id', 'row2').insertAfter('#row');
```

and then make sure that the original `#row` element was kept hidden with CSS.

Generalizing this question, would having a hidden DOM element and then cloning that element when it is needed a good practice for jQuery?  Or is there a cleaner solution for this type of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah use backbone.js, define a template and write to the dom that way. Very clean.

Comment: If you want to modify the ID, you should use `attr` method, there is no `id` method in jQuery.

Comment: @undefined Yeah, sorry about that, I just wrote a quick one-liner and I often forget I cannot access id directly.  Fixed now!

Comment: Seems like you could use some templating, try underscore templates. Otherwise I would just write the html because the clone will keep the ids, text etc and you'd have to clean that afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of hardcoding the format into JavaScript, this is really the best way to go about it.

The other way you *could* do it is by copying an existing row (of data) and removing all the text from the elements. Then you get a clone without the invisible row.

There are also plugins to handle this, like [`dynoTable`](http://www.seomoves.org/blog/web-design-development/dynotable-a-jquery-plugin-by-bob-tantlinger-2683/) and [others](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+table+row+clone+plugin).